# Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON policy

Tags: amazon-web-services

please I am getting this error when i ran Terraform plan.can anyone help look at my policy to see where i am making mistake.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-sam-sandbox/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-sam-sandbox"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:1234567980:key/18d052ff-6705-43aa-b"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What error exactly? And what is your TF code that you actually use for that policy?

Answer (score 0):

`1234567980` is not a valid account number. AWS account numbers are 12 digits. If I put a random 12-digit value in there, IAM allows me to create this policy without a problem, so the rest of it is valid.

Since it's invalid and clearly a made-up number, I'm guessing you copy-pasted this from somewhere? You need to get the ARN from the KMS key resource (if you created it via Terraform).